# Help evaluating PHP in .tpl files

Tags: php, template-engine

I use this function to load template files:

```
public function loadTemplate ($replaceToken = array(), $path = 'master.tpl') {
    $template = $this->tru->objectFactory('file', $this->tru->config->get('root.path').'/lib/template/email/'.$path);

    $templateContent = $template->readAll();

    if (count($replaceToken) > 0) {
        foreach ($replaceToken as $token => $value) {
            $templateContent = str_replace('{$'.$token.'}', $value, $templateContent);
        }
    }

    return $templateContent;
}
```

It allows me to call variables such as `{$title}`.  This has been sufficient for now with very basic emails.  But now I'm getting to the point where I need to use loops and thus need to be able to run PHP in these .tpl files.  I'm struggling to determine the best route, I know eval() is rarely a good solution, but is it he right solution here?

Here's an example of one of my tpl files:

```
            <tr style='border-top: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);'>
                <td style='border-color: #ccc; border-style: solid none; border-width: 1px medium; color: #494949 !important; padding: 5px 10px !important; font-size: 12px;'>Description</td>
                <td style='border-color: #ccc; border-style: solid none; border-width: 1px medium; color: #494949 !important; padding: 5px 10px !important; font-size: 12px;'>Vehicle</td>
                <td style='border-color: #ccc; border-style: solid none; border-width: 1px medium; color: #494949 !important; padding: 5px 10px !important; font-size: 12px; text-align: right;'>Unit price</td>
                <td style='border-color: #ccc; border-style: solid none; border-width: 1px medium; color: #494949 !important; padding: 5px 10px !important; font-size: 12px; text-align: right;'>Qty</td>
                <td style='border-color: #ccc; border-style: solid none; border-width: 1px medium; color: #494949 !important; padding: 5px 10px !important; font-size: 12px; text-align: right;'>Amount</td>
            </tr>
            <?
            foreach ($order['productList'] as $product) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px <?=$product['border']?> rgb(204, 204, 204); color: #666 !important;'><?=$product['title']?></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px <?=$product['border']?> rgb(204, 204, 204); color: #666 !important;'><?=$product['vehicle']?></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px <?=$product['border']?> rgb(204, 204, 204); color: #666 !important; text-align: right;'>$<?=$product['price']?></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px <?=$product['border']?> rgb(204, 204, 204); color: #666 !important; text-align: right;'><?=$product['quantity']?></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px <?=$product['border']?> rgb(204, 204, 204); color: #666 !important; text-align: right;'>$<?=$product['lineTotal']?></td>
            </tr>
            <?
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='3'></td>
                <td style='padding: 2px 5px; text-align: right; font-size: 12px;'>Subtotal</td>
                <td style='padding: 2px 5px; text-align: right; font-size: 12px;'>$<?=$order['subtotal']?></td>
            </tr>
```

**update**

What are the security risks with using `eval()` like this:

```
public function loadTemplate ($replaceToken = array(), $path = 'master.tpl') {
    $template = $this->tru->objectFactory('file', $this->tru->config->get('root.path').'/lib/template/email/'.$path);

    $templateContent = $template->readAll();

    if (count($replaceToken) > 0) {
        foreach ($replaceToken as $token => $value) {
            $$token = $value;
            $templateContent = str_replace('{$'.$token.'}', $value, $templateContent);
        }
    }

    ob_start();
    eval('?>'.$templateContent.'<?');
    $templateContent = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $templateContent;
}
```

I can't think of how this could be insecure.  The variables even if they contain PHP code aren't being eval()'d so our .tpl files (which require our own developer access anyways)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a Smarty tag.  If so, you wrap PHP in a {php} tag.

Edit to add code sample:

```
This is a smarty tag: {$title}

{* this is a smarty foreach loop *}
{forach from=$some_array item=i}
    {$i}
{/foreach}

{php}
// this is literal PHP within a smarty template
foreach ($some_array as $k=>$v) {
   print $k.'=>'.$v.'<br />';
}
{/php}
```

Comment: But how can I execute the loop?

Comment: Edited answer to include code sample for Smarty... though you have not confirmed you are indeed using it.

Answer (score 0):

You might take the challenge and write yourself a custom parser for that problem.

The easier and more fitting way for your question would be to use already existing templating engines like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). With it, you can either define own functions (so-called "blocks") that do the actual PHP execution or use pre-defined directives (`{foreach ...}`).

It'll go pretty smooth with your existing template style, since Smarty evaluates template variables like in your example: they're expressed as `{$variable}`.

---

**EDIT**

I feel bad, typing this. `eval` is actually a typo. The `a` is actually an `i`. Here we go:

**This is a way to accomplish your goal** but *please* do not use this in a production environment:

```
$template = '<?php for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { ?>
    <b>something</b><?php
} ?>';

eval('?>' . $template);
```

This [codepad snippet](http://codepad.org/r5Gbaz5h) gives you a demonstration of ten "foo"s.

Comment: I've used Smarty before... I'd like to just be able to execute some basic PHP (echoing variables and loops) without the overhead of a complex application like Smarty

Comment: @Webnet Sorry, then, mate. You'll have to design a **good** parser that distinguishes your HTML from PHP. And that *is* complex. For such a simple requirement, you're better off using Smarty/`<insert-template-engine-here>`.